# how to show username with user field type in advanced custom fields plugin

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i create a user relational type field in acf, after selecting user, acf just returns user id, my question is how to return the selected user "first name" or email address on my page?

[image]

i tried User Array and User Object mode, but i did not get the result.
Can anyone guide me to work with User Array / User Object mode.

i cant find documents in acf website about this.
thanks

i use this code:

php the_field('inscourse');

Answer (score 1):

For User Array selected, just put something like this to see the returned vales:

```
$inscourse = get_field('inscourse'); 
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($inscourse); 
echo '</pre>';
```

This will output a nested array like:

```
array(
[ID] => 123
[user_firstname] => Joe
[user_lastname] => Jackson
....
[user_nicename] => joe-jackson
[display_name] => Joe
....
)
```